# What factors affect the base address of a shared object?

Tags: linux, exploit, mips, libraries

I'm looking at a CVE for an old thrift shop router that amounts to a stack based buffer overflow with no `NULL` characters allowed. I can control the instruction pointer register as well as a few less useful registers. My goal is to perform a stack pivot to something I control. The router runs on MIPS big endian architecture so I can't leave the last 8 bits of a payload empty to get a leading `NULL` in an address. e.g. 0x00XXXXXX. I'm left to look for gadgets in shared objects (or the stack if cache flushed). I find that shared objects are generally loaded at higher addresses that make use of all 32 bits of the address. I cannot use gadgets from the vulnerable process because it was not compiled with `-fpie` and it loads at the same address with a leading `NULL` every time.

If I consistently want to be able to use gadgets in a shared object, it will need to be loaded with the same base address most of the time. Assuming no ASLR (not enabled on my router), what determines where a shared object will be loaded?

If I run `ldd` on the target binary, I get this:

```
$ mips-linux-ldd squashfs-root/sbin/my_binary
    /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 => /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0 (0x00000000)
```

Not super useful. I know that `ld-uClibc.so.0` doesn't get loaded at `0x00000000` and that there are several other libraries that get loaded for this process (not `dlopen`'ed) which are not listed. Perhaps the non-useful output is a toolchain thing or due to the fact that I'm not running on the target architecture.

Under the hood, I'd think we're looking at `mmap` logic.

I found this in an article from Oracle:

> An executable or shared object file's base address is calculated during execution from three values: the memory load address, the maximum page size, and the lowest virtual address of a program's loadable segment

To me it seems like these things would never change when working with a specific firmware version where the binaries can always be expected to be the same.

My questions are:

- Will shared objects get loaded in the same place every time on a Linux system with ASLR disabled?

  - Is the mapping deterministic?
- What factors, if any will make the shared object map to a different address?

  - Perhaps 2 libraries conflict in a preferred address
- Iff library loading is deterministic, can I assume the shared object will always be at the same address after checking once? The word *deterministic* answers my own question, but I want to be clear.